# Is it possible to configure Microsoft DFS using Samba for Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, dfs

On Windows it is possible to create DFS using windows share. However, I'm using Linux server and wondering - is it possible to create MSDFS using Samba on Linux?

What configuration changes needed to do it?

Comment: AFACT, DFS is just file sharing with more flexible path naming.  that's standard on any file system on Unix-like systems.  NFS would do

Comment: @Javier That may apply to DFSN (DFS Namespaces), but DFS also includes replication as part of the system.

Comment: @Javier it's not only flexible path naming, but grouping (possible 10 or 50 servers) into one, kinda gateway for the user.  In space of http servers or k8s ingress - this is usual thing

Answer (score 8):

Samba can do it through special symbolic link files. Samba has to be compiled with the `--with-msdfs` option to make it work. Then you need to modify the smb.conf file to turn it on.

```
[global]
    host msdfs = yes

 #Add DFS as a share definition
[dfs]
    path = /srv/smb/dfsroot
    msdfs root = yes
```

Once it does, you can make symlinks with this syntax to emulate linking to a remote host:

```
ln -s 'msdfs:server\volume` accounting
```

Lower-case is key. If you're replicating the data somehow (Samba, unlike Microsoft, doesn't bundle replication in with DFS) you can emulate that as well.

```
ln -s 'msdfs:server1\acct,msdfs:server2\acct' accounting
```

It's a good idea to ensure the links are owned by root. You don't want stray users redirecting other users to places nefarious.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try [MooseFS](https://moosefs.com/) - an open-source distributed file system for Linux. It's fault-tolerant and has got a lot of different useful technical features.

Answer (score 1):

A quick trip to your search engine of choice would bring up [Ceph](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-ceph/?ca=drs-), [Lustre](http://wiki.lustre.org) and gFarm to name but three, obviously you're free to discover more options via the same route.

Comment: nah, Ceph  is not even close to MSDFS and the way how both work

Answer (score -1):

yes, you have the [global file system (GFS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_File_System) [red hat link](http://www.redhat.com/gfs/)

Comment: I don't think that's anything like Windows' DFS. GFS sounds like a filesystem for clusters, based on shared storage, e.g. a SAN LUN. Windows DFS provides an abstraction layer for UNC paths, so that \\domain\share\somefolder may reside on multiple servers, with the client selecting one based on various criteria. It also provides for replication of the data between servers. DFS works quite well even over WAN links.